# Vungle and Facebook not working together in iOS

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, vungle-ads

I have a game which is made with `Unity`, using both Facebook and Vungle SDKs. This works fine for me in the Android build.

However, when I port this to an iOS project and try to build it, I am getting link errors. Looking through the errors I can see that one of either Vungle or Facebook is always missing. Moreover when i first make the XCode project it has Vungle SDK included but not Facebook and, if I  build again to XCode it will have Facebook but no Vungle SDK.

Any subsequent builds come with Facebook only. I have tried many times to rebuild the project. Now is there a way that i could merge these two projects if at all it is possible?

This is giving me the link errors. Can any one tell me whether i am doing something wrong.

The screenshots for the images can be downloaded from the links below:

[image: With Vungle]

[image: With Facebook]

Also, I can see that Facebook is replaced by a StoreKit framework. Did anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like both SDKs are rebuilding the Xcode framework search paths / linked frameworks from scratch.

You might be able to get around the issue by exporting the project with Facebook included, and then manually adding the Vungle SDK framework into the Xcode project (outlined at https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204430550-Get-Started-with-Vungle-iOS-SDK).